# Laravel 5 jQuery ajax post throws a Controller method not found error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

This is my routes.php

```
Route::controller('user','UserController');
```

My javascript code which is in my blade file

```
  jQuery.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"/user/login-from-fb/",
            data:{
                data:data,
                _token: "<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>"
            },
            success:function(data){

            }
        });
```

In my UserController.php

```
public function postLoginFromFb(){
    $data = \Input::all();
    var_dump($data);
    die;
}
```

This is my code but looks like i am always getting an error.
This is the error:

```
Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

NotFoundHttpException in Controller.php line 259: Controller method not found.
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Your help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks! :)

Comment: your url is diferent from the route controller

Comment: @madalinivascu i think not, I think what `Route::controller('user','UserController');` means is that when you have `/user` in the url, you are referring that to all functions/method in your `UserController` file

Comment: did you send csrf token?

Comment: @user3621494 if you looked at my code, you'll see that I sent it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using this types url

```
<?php echo URL::to('user/login-from-fb') ?>
```

Comment: and one more thing, `Input::all()` is not used in Laravel 5. You should use `Request::all()` in order to retrieve request parameters @PinoyStackOverflower

Comment: This made my work so I'm up voting it. But, does any one have a explanation why it works?